# Seperate Pact Interactions in Provider Verification Tests by Endpoint

Tags: pact, pact-jvm

I just started to adopt Pact test for my system that consists of one provider service and an Angular frontend as the consumer. I succeeded in setting up both sides, thus, the Angular application generates a (single) pact file with many interactions to multiple endpoints of my provider service. In the provider, I do now face the issue that my verification test gets very large and overly complicated since I have to mock all my endpoints in a single test with all their data, e.g.:

```java
@Provider("example-backend")
@PactFolder("pacts")
@SpringBootTest(...)
class ComprehensivePactTest {

    [...]

    @State("healthy")
    fun `healthy state`() {
        whenever(exampleService.dosomething(any())).thenReturn(exampleResponse)
        whenever(otherService.somethingElse()).thenReturn(otherResponse)
    }
}
```

Is there a way to seperate the interaction from the pact file such that I could have multiple small verification tests in my provider? For instance, I would like to have a verification test for all requests with path starting with "/example" and a second test for path starting with "/other".

So what I would prefer to have is smaller, focused verification test like so:

```java
@Provider("example-backend")
@PactFolder("pacts")
@SpringBootTest(...)
class ExampleEndpointPactTest {

    [... include some filter logic here ...]

    @State("healthy")
    fun `healthy state`() {
        whenever(exampleService.dosomething(any())).thenReturn(exampleResponse)
    }
}

@Provider("example-backend")
@PactFolder("pacts")
@SpringBootTest(...)
class OtherEndpointPactTest {

    [... include some filter logic here ...]

    @State("healthy")
    fun `healthy state`() {
        whenever(otherService.somethingElse()).thenReturn(otherResponse)
    }
}
```

Or do I have a fallacy in my thinking? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JUnit4 Readme has a section about this topic. I think it also applies to Junit5 https://github.com/DiUS/pact-jvm/tree/master/provider/pact-jvm-provider-junit#using-multiple-classes-for-the-state-change-methods

> Using multiple classes for the state change methods
>
> If you have a large number of state change methods, you can split
>   things up by moving them to other classes. There are two ways you can
>   do this: Use interfaces
>
> You can put the state change methods on interfaces and then have your
>   test class implement those interfaces. See
>   StateAnnotationsOnInterfaceTest for an example. Specify the additional
>   classes on the test target
>
> You can provide the additional classes to the test target with the
>   withStateHandler or setStateHandlers methods. See
>   BooksPactProviderTest for an example.